# Issue with Date formats conversion

Tags: javascript

I have the following date format : `2020-09-25T11:09:00.422Z`, which in order to be processed, needs to be modified to the following format:  `Wed Apr 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100`
How to achieve that in a one liner ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Date` instance and pass the value as `string`:

```
new Date("2020-09-25T11:09:00.422Z")
```

Comment: You don't need to import. Everything in JavaScript is already available in React

Comment: Happy to help you!